# Pulling Scalars Out of Inner Products

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong with the following logic:

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and let $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Consider the expression: $$x^* \lambda x.$$

On the one hand: 
\begin{align*}
x^* \lambda x &=  (x^*\lambda)x\\
&= <\lambda x, x>\\
&= \lambda ||x||^2
\end{align*}

On the other hand: 
\begin{align*}
x^* \lambda x &=  x^*(\lambda x)\\
&= <x, \lambda x>\\
&= \lambda^* ||x||^2
\end{align*}

which seemingly imples that $\lambda = \lambda^*$ which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in thinking that
$$(x^*\lambda) x$$
Is the same as
$$\langle \lambda x, x\rangle$$
It is actually
$$\langle\lambda^*x, x\rangle$$
Here I'm assuming that
$$\langle x, y\rangle=x^*y$$
Your convention might be different.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the reason because I skipped taking a transpose, and that I need the $x^*$ and $x$ to be next to each other before converting to the $<>$ notation. Yes, I am assuming that $<x,y> = x^*y$.

Comment: @open Essentially. $x^*\lambda=(\lambda^*x) ^*$.

Comment: So does all of this imply that in general $x^* \lambda x \neq \lambda x^* x$? Why doesn't this conflict with matrices being linear?

Comment: @Open $x^*\lambda x=\lambda x^*x$.

Comment: @Open Sorry I misread your comment. See the edit.

Comment: but if $x^* \lambda x = \lambda x^* x$ then couldn't I still show that $x^* \lambda x = \lambda ||x||^2$ by first pulling out the lambda and then converting to the inner product leading to a contradiction?

Comment: @open Yes, it is equal to $\lambda\|x\|^2$.

Comment: But then $(x^*\lambda) x = \langle\lambda^*x, x\rangle = \lambda ^* ||x||^2$ which is a contradiction? Essentially at the end of the day I am trying to understand if the expression $x^* \lambda x$ equals $\lambda ^* ||x||^2$ or $\lambda ||x||^2$

Comment: @openset If you’re still in doubt, expand all of the expressions explicitly in terms of coordinates and see what you get. Remember, too, that a Hermitian (complex) inner product is _anti_linear in one of its arguments.